# Node.js on nginx with different port

Tags: node.js, nginx, https

I have seen few examples in internet but tried none of them is working, can you tell whats wrong i am doing. I have my laravel app on nginx server , now i want to run another node.js app on different port on my server. i have been trying on different ways , but all i am getting "**502 Bad Gateway**"

Another note, i have my HTTPS port allowed for port 3000.

Here's my server config codes-

```
server{
    listen 443 ssl;
#   listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    server_name node.example.com;
    root /home/Tapos/node_modules;
    index index.html index.htm index.js;
    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   proxy_pass https://node.example.com;
        proxy_pass https://localhost:3000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add another `server` block for redirecting the traffic to another nodejs app or update the existing `server` block to redirect the traffic between your nodejs application based on the URL.

Please add your updated server block or new server block to the question if you need any further help.

Comment: well, all my existing apps are working on port 80 and 443 . all i want is just add a simple node program so it can work along side with my existing app. so i just enabled port 3000 to pass through it. but not sure how its going to work here.

Comment: `504 Bad Gateway` says that, your upstream(nodejs app running on 3000) is not returning anything to nginx. Do you have the nodejs app running and listening on 3000 port? What does `sudo netstat -lnp | grep 3000` is returning?

Comment: returning nothing. so what am i missing here?

Comment: Which means, your nodejs application is not running. Did you start your nodejs app?

Comment: OK. What is the error you are seeing now? Still 504? Can you check it running the same command? `sudo netstat -lnp | grep 3000`. Can you post the output here?

Comment: yes, "502 Bad Gateway" error. and the command output is nothing. no line

Comment: output of command line showing

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1070/nginx

when i added on server block to "listen 3000;"

Comment: Looks like your nodejs app is not running. You have to fix that first. Do you have any logs for the nodejs app?

Comment: error while run:
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1039:14)
    at listen (net.js:1061:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1135:5)
    at EventEmitter.listen (/home/Tapos/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:617:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/Tapos/node_modules/index.js:34:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)

Comment: if i changed the port from 3000 to 5000, and then if i run it says, "running on port 5000..."

Comment: what does `sudo nestat -lnp | grep 5000` says?

Comment: EADDRINUSE(Address in use) error is due to the change you have made to nginx  -  `listen 3000`.

Comment: Something wrong with your nodejs app. It might be starting fine, but looks like it is not hanging there. You should always have the process(which is returned when you run that netstat command with grepping the port number.)